# proving $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n} = 1$

Tags: calculus

Can anyone explain me to how can I prove that:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n} = 1
$$

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Given:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^n\cdot (1)(2)(3)(4)\cdots(n)}{\sqrt{2\pi n} \cdot \underbrace{(n)(n)(n)(n)\cdots(n)}_{n \text{ times}}}
$$

Now how can I solve it after that?

Help Required.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/stirling.pdf Here's a decent proof.

Comment: Thanks Raghav and Alec....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely non-trivial, and it is known as Stirling's formula.  Here is an outline of a proof using the Gamma function.  Using Lebesgue's dominated convergence I think it can be made rigorous.

$$ n! = \int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x} \, dx = \sqrt n \int_{-\sqrt n}^\infty \left(n+\sqrt n y\right)^n \exp \left(-n-\sqrt n y\right) \, dy \\ = \sqrt n \left(\frac ne\right)^n \int_{-\sqrt n}^\infty \left(\left(1+\frac y{\sqrt n}\right)\exp\left(-\frac y{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^n \, dy \\= \sqrt n \left(\frac ne\right)^n \int_{-\sqrt n}^\infty\left(1-\frac {y^2}{2 n} + O\left(\frac{y^2}{2n}\right)^{3/2}\right)^n \, dy \\ \sim \sqrt n \left(\frac ne\right)^n \int_{-\sqrt n}^\infty e^{-y^2/2} \, dy \sim \sqrt n \left(\frac ne\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi}$$